# How is the Affine connection related to the Affine group?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

I'm simultaneously learning some group theory and differential geometry in different contexts and I find myself wondering....

We utilize an affine connection in general relativity (specifically a torsionless levi-cevita type usually), but can imagine using a general affine connection as well. No group theory is ever mentioned.

On the other side of the coin, I'm learning that the double cover of the Poincare group is the special affine group, which has innumerable physical applications. What's the deal, the two are clearly related in some way, but neither class mentions anything suggesting the link.

Comment: It's all about whether you think of the tangent space at a point of the manifold as a *vector space* (so the associated frame bundle has group $GL(n)$) or as an *affine vector space* (so the associated frame bundle has group $A(n)$, the group of affine transformations). The torsion of a connection measures the infinitesimal change of the base point of the affine tangent vectors.